# Different processing time for the same function

Tags: for-loop, image-processing, matrix, time, raster

I am using a for loop to create a new matrix with average/maximum/minimum values based on combining 25x25 cells in an old matrix. However, this code takes different times to run on seperate matrices that should be identical.

I have 2 rasters called A and B (same resolution and extent):
A (2317392 elements, 18.3Mb)
B (2317392 elements, 17.7Mb)

Converted to a matrix:
Ma (2317392 elements, 17.7Mb)
Mb (2317392 elements, 17.7Mb)

Running the code:

```
maxm <- matrix(nrow=nrow(Ma)/25, ncol=ncol(Ma)/25)
for(i in 1:dim(maxm)[1] {
   for(j in 1:dim(maxm)[2] {
      row <- 25 * (i-1) + 1
      col <- 25 * (j-1) + 1
   maxm[i,j] <- max(A[row:(row + 24), col:(col + 24)])
   }
}
```

For 'Ma' it runs in 13.25 Secs

The same code running on matrix 'Mb' takes 13.2 Secs.
This is as I expected it to be.

## -----------

However,
If I change the extent to cover a larger area of the raster and run the same code.

This time, Ma2 (41320312 elements, 315.2Mb) and Mb2 (41320312 elements, 315.2Mb)

The code running on Ma2 takes 245.84 Secs

However the code running on Mb2 runs for days.....

I have looked at removing NA values, such as:

```
maxm[i,j] <- max(A[row:(row + 24), col:(col + 24)], na.rm=TRUE)
```

I cant understand why it would be so much slower to run on what should be the same process. Any thoughts/ideas would be greatly appreciated!